# newTextField overlapping newRect in group

Tags: coronasdk

I have a problem with Corona SDK. I want my newRect to overlap newTextField control. My code:

```
local localGroup = display.newGroup()

local txtOne = display.newTextField( display.contentWidth/2 - 140, 260, 280, 60)
 local txtTwo= display.newTextField( display.contentWidth/2 - 140, 360, 280, 60)
 local rect= display.newRect( display.contentWidth/2 - 140, 160, 200, 360)

localGroup:insert(txtOne)
 localGroup:insert(txtTwo)
 localGroup:insert(rect)
```

Result i have: txtOne and txtTwo always overlapping my rect object. But I want rect object to be on top of
 txtOne and txtTwo. Is there a way to do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to the [docs](http://docs.coronalabs.com/api/library/native/newTextField.html#TOC)

> Because native textfields are not part of the OpenGL canvas, they do
>   not obey the Corona display object hierarchy. They always appear
>   above normal display objects, and cannot be inserted into display
>   groups.

So you can't bring the rect object in front.

You can work around it if you want. Just hide the textfield when not necessary

Comment: Yes. I have the same answer from Corona. I guess the only workaround is fade out the text fields.

Answer (score -1):

Read [This](http://developer.coronalabs.com/reference/index/objecttofront) link.

Try:
rect:toFront()

Read [this](http://developer.coronalabs.com/node/2600) link for creating textfield.

Comment: Unfortunatelly it does not work. It workd with other objects (tested with newRect, it works), but not with newTextField (they are still on top of newRect).

Comment: let try like this txtOne:toBack() or use different group. insert txtOne,txtTwo into one group,newRect into another group use tofront,toback.or localGroup:insert(2,rect);localGroup:insert(1,txtOne)
 localGroup:insert(1,txtTwo)

Comment: No,sorry, it didn`t work as well. The only workaround for me was to use transition.to and fade out txtOne and txtTwo whenever I needed... :(